Why my calculations for the eccentric anomalies at the start and end of an interplanetery transfer seem to be off?
For a game, to determine an interplanetary transfer I have implemented the method from here. Using the data for their example problem, I get the result with the lowest $\Delta v$ which appears plausible, for a transfer from Earth to Mars.
Departing on 20/07/2020 Arriving on 25/01/2021
Transit duration: 189.27 days
Total deltaV: 7154.86 m/s^2

Several calculations later, I determine the semimajor axis $a$ of the transfer orbit and then determine an ellipse (for plotting the trajectory) having as first focus the position of the Sun $(0,0,0)$ in the simulation and as second focus $f_2=-2a\vec{e}$ where $e$ is the eccentricity vector
Successively, I calculate the Eccentric anomaly at the starting position and final position using the ellipse, and I get two angles, $e_0$ and $e_1$. I then plot the trajectory in my game and it only renders correctly if I make these corrections:
$$e_0'=-e_0$$
$$e_1'=-e_1+2\pi$$
With $e_0'$ and $e_1'$ being the "correct" eccentric anomalies for the start and end of the transfer orbit. This transformation seems to hold true for every start date combination I have tested so far. If I don't apply this transformation, the trajectory starts and end in the wrong position (a bit "ahead" in time of where the starting planet is).
Two questions:

This seems to be the result of a coordinate mismatch somewhere. What kind of error could lead to this situation?
After reading a bit on the topic I thought that the interplanetary transfer was supposed to "span" $180^\circ$ from the start, however the values I'm getting with different start dates seem to vary. With the starting conditions above, the delta between $e_1'$ and $e_0'$ is $~132^\circ$. With other starting dates, it can be even higher than $180^\circ$, but the trajectories are all visually correct at least. The planet is always in the correct position at start and likewise for the final planet at arrival. Did I misunderstand something?


Question 1: your statement " it only renders correctly if " makes me think you have misunderstood a graphing program you obtained (not wrote). Other things look good, except eccentric anomaly is always capital $E$. I hope you have looked elsewhere to understand how $E$ and true anomaly are related geometrically.

@WHG I wish the program appeared out of thin air in my PC, but no I didnt "obtain it". I implemented it largely based on the link in the question and other resources on the web. I mean the procedure to calculate orbital elements doesn't allow for a lot of creativity. But yes, my background is not physics.
